# FullCalendar - Header/Title to custom <DIV>?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have build up a custom header in my Full-Calendar project. I control the full calendar functions from my own buttons.

I want to disable the original FC-Header, but I want to keep the "**Title**".
Exactly I want to **move the Title to a custom** .
Please have a look at the following **screenshot** to get an idea of what I'm talking:

[Screenshot - Custom Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK081.png)

Is this possible? How to?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes this can be done easily by using the [`viewRender`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) callback. It gives you access to the [`View Object`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View_Object/) which you can grab the title from. So in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5LzesoL/) I have set up my calendar to not display a title and then in the `viewRender` function I grab the title and use jquery to place it into my external element. `viewRender` will be called when your calendar view changes so it should stay updated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek'
      },
      defaultView: 'month',
      viewRender: function(view) {
        var title = view.title;
        $("#externalTitle").html(title);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Many many thanks! This works absolutely perfect!!! :-) :-) :-)
Thought I will have to touch the source!
You are the best!

Comment: For future visitors: `v4` has many breaking changes, esp. removal of jQuery. Anyway, this function is now replaced with `datesRender` (and  `viewSkeletonRender`) as per the [official upgrade guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3#view-rendering)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you guys for the combined effort!

Comment: For future visitors: in react you have to use `<FullCalendar viewDidMount={(view) => {console.log(view)}} />`